# boost_thread not linking on NaCl

Tags: boost, boost-thread, google-nativeclient

I receive this error when linking -lboost_thread into my executable on google Native Client (pepper_19):

nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/mac_x86_glibc/x86_64-nacl/usr/lib/libboost_thread.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

I compiled boost according to the instructions at naclports here: http://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/InstallingSDL (except using the boost library directory instead of SDL... I also used this same process to correctly compile NaCl zlib library)

```
cd naclports/src/libraries/boost_1_47_0

export NACL_PACKAGES_BITSIZE=32; ./nacl-boost_1_47_0.sh
export NACL_PACKAGES_BITSIZE=64; ./nacl-boost_1_47_0.sh
```

this generates the libboost_thread.a file and puts it them in the /usr/lib directories of my NACL installation.  I thought maybe somehow I mistakenly built a wrong type of library for linking with NaCl.  Is there a way to check this and/or fix it?

I tried:

```
cd naclports/src/out/repository-x86_64/boost_1_47_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/link-static/threading-multi

nm libboost_thread.a
```

and this yielded:

```
libboost_thread.a(thread.o):
0000000000052d08 s EH_frame0
000000000004f50c s GCC_except_table100
000000000004f534 s GCC_except_table101
000000000004f574 s GCC_except_table102
000000000004f5c0 s GCC_except_table103
000000000004f600 s GCC_except_table104
000000000004f64c s GCC_except_table105
000000000004f68c s GCC_except_table106
000000000004f6d8 s GCC_except_table107
.
.
.
.
```

etc, etc..
However then I ran:

nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/mac_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-nm libboost_thread.a

and got:

```
__.SYMDEF SORTED: File format not recognized
nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/mac_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-nm: thread.o: File format not recognized
nacl_sdk/pepper_19/toolchain/mac_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-nm: once.o: File format not recognized
```

And finally. I ran:

```
file pthread/thread.o
pthread/thread.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
```

however the same command on a zlib object file results in:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1, not stripped
```

I would appreciate advice on building a correctly cross-compiled NaCl libboost_thread.a

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries in NaCl ports can only be built on linux. So you have to either find why boost decides to use system ar instead of x86_64-nacl-ar or install VM with linux where they are the same.